# joining two table not working as expected

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, self-join, join

I have been working on this for about two days now and cant seem to figure it out so I would love some help.

I have two tables:

```
mysql> select id, date, volume, symbol_id  from control_quotedaily limit 5;
+-------+---- -------+----------+-----------+
| id    | date       | volume   | symbol_id |
+-------+------------+----------+-----------+
| 13263 | 2017-11-02 |  7800191 | AXISBANK  |
| 13264 | 2017-11-02 |  9303981 | SBIN      |
| 13265 | 2017-11-02 |  8013536 | HDFCBANK  |
| 13266 | 2017-11-03 |  9642624 | AXISBANK  |
| 13267 | 2017-11-04 | 19642327 | AXISBANK  |
+-------+------------+----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
14 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from control_oidaily
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| symbol_id | date       | expiry_date | val_in_lakhs |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| AXISBANK  | 2017-11-02 | 2017-11-30  |     166881.8 |
| AXISBANK  | 2017-11-02 | 2017-12-28  |      2676.84 |
| AXISBANK  | 2017-11-02 | 2018-01-25  |        97.13 |
| HDFCBANK  | 2017-11-02 | 2017-11-30  |     76351.11 |
| HDFCBANK  | 2017-11-02 | 2017-12-28  |      1509.48 |
| HDFCBANK  | 2017-11-02 | 2018-01-25  |            0 |
| SBIN      | 2017-11-02 | 2017-11-30  |      88654.3 |
| SBIN      | 2017-11-02 | 2017-12-28  |      1060.51 |
| SBIN      | 2017-11-02 | 2018-01-25  |            0 |
| AXISBANK  | 2017-11-03 | 2017-11-30  |     87640.06 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

So for every quote in the control_quotedaily table this is what I want:

1. closest expiry_date for that quote from the control_oidaily table
2. I want the val_in_lakhs for that expiry_date.

Eg: For date 2017-11-02, the closest expiry is 2017-11-30 and I want the val_in_lakhs (76351.11) returned.

This is what I am trying:

```
select o.date, o.expiry_date as expiry_date, o.symbol_id, q.date, q.symbol_id, o.val_in_lakhs, q.tottrdval, q.volume, q.symbol_id
FROM control_oidaily o
JOIN ( select o.date, MIN(expiry_date) as expiry_date, symbol_id
    FROM control_oidaily o
    GROUP by o.date,o.symbol_id                 
    ORDER BY o.date asc) as ed
ON ed.date = o.date 
    AND ed.symbol_id = o.symbol_id
    AND ed.expiry_date = o.expiry_date
JOIN control_quotedaily q
ON q.date = ed.date
    AND q.symbol_id = ed.symbol_id
```

This is the output I am expecting:

```
+-------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| id    | date       | volume   | symbol_id | expiry_date  | val_in_lakhs |
+-------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 13263 | 2017-11-02 |  7800191 | AXISBANK  | 2017-11-30   |     166881.8 |
| 13264 | 2017-11-02 |  9303981 | SBIN      | 2017-11-30   |      88654.3 |
| 13265 | 2017-11-02 |  8013536 | HDFCBANK  | 2017-11-30   |     76351.11 |
| 13266 | 2017-11-03 |  9642624 | AXISBANK  | 2017-11-30   |     87640.06 |
+-------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: which data type is the column  expiry_date ??  and what is you actual result for the sample provided  (2017-11-02, the closest expiry is 2017-11-30? ??

Comment: What version of MySQL? (important, v8 is now available) Does **closest** mean **less than or equal to**? Does table `control_quotedaily` contain an `expiry_date` column? (You don't display it.)

Comment: There are 3 expiry dates for 2017-11-30 why do you pick 76351.11 in preference to the other two?

Comment: The datatype for expiry_date is datetime. closest is greater than or equal to

Comment: Order by in a subquery without top/limit is a nop. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn how to have a non-poster user notified that you commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), get the `closest_expiry_date` (minimum value of `expiry_date`), for a grouping of `symbol_id` and `date`, from `control_oidaily` table.
- Join this with the `control_quotedaily` table on `symbol_id` and `date`, to get closest_expiry_date value for every row in the `control_quotedaily` table.
- Now, use the same derived table again to join with `control_oidaily` table, matching up on `date`, `expiry_date` (with closest expiry date) and `symbol_id` to get `val_in_lakhs`.

You possibly want the following query:

```
SELECT q.id, 
       q.`date`, 
       q.volume, 
       q.symbol_id, 
       o1.expiry_date, 
       o1.val_in_lakhs 
FROM control_quotedaily AS q 
JOIN (SELECT o2.`date`, 
             o2.symbol_id
             MIN(o2.expiry_date) as closest_expiry_date              
      FROM control_oidaily AS o2
      GROUP by o2.`date`, o2.symbol_id                 
     ) AS dt 
  ON dt.`date` = q.`date` 
     AND dt.symbol_id = q.symbol_id
JOIN control_oidaily AS o1 
  ON dt.`date` = o1.`date`
     AND dt.symbol_id = o1.symbol_id 
     AND dt.closest_expiry_date = o1.expiry_date
```

Comment: Thats awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: Im sorry but on double checking this does not work :(

Comment: @avrgeo What is the issue ? Can you create a DB Fiddle or SQL fiddle to test against.

Comment: I have updated the description with more symbols. Your query only returns AXISBANK which mine was doing as well. I am unable to get it for all the symbols. maybe you can take another look please, thanks again for the help

Comment: @avrgeo my query is symbol_id agnostic. Can you setup a https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: @avrgeo Also, edit the question to add expected output as per your updated sample data.

Comment: thanks , i have edited the comment and added the desierd output. i havent used db-fiddle but will try it

Comment: @avrgeo any luck with setting up db-fiddle ? Or, you can do is, give me: result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE control_quotedaily` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE control_oidaily`

Comment: @avrgeo I have checked my query again, made a small fix because `date` is a reserved keyword. It should really work, unless your sample data is not real representative of actual data

Comment: I have double checked and now it works as expected. Thank you very much!